# Where does this post belong?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I posted this to Psychology because it is a broad question that happens to be a current issue for me. [what is trying, and how can i do it?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/23368/what-is-trying-and-how-can-i-do-it/2337) Apparently that's not allowed. Is there a better place for this question?

Comment: It doesn’t belong, I’m sorry. It’s too specific to you, and across SE the idea is to build libraries of Qs that are useful for *many people*. As for explicit feedback on “lack of effort”: EL&U is my main site so I’ll start there. Proofreading is clearly and explicitly off-topic there, so one piece of work you unquestionably did not do is read the help before asking. You’re savvy enough with the network to navigate multiple sites, so ignorance isn’t an excuse. You just didn’t do it first. Another example is your SU question on periodic shutdowns: *what did you try to solve this yourself*? Etc

Comment: One way to benchmark yourself is to enforce a self-imposed time budget. You must spend 2 hours (say) actively, dedicatedly, and focusedly on trying to solve the problem yourself, meanwhile writing down everything you’re trying, where it led you, what questions were answered and which are still open and why, and *put all this into your questions*, in a clear, comprehensible, structured, and digestible way that trades off *your effort* in writing for your anticipated audiences’ ease of reading. I mean what books, what Wikipedia articles, what google searches, what command lines, etc. Real work.

Comment: Another example is your cwrsync question: literally just an error log. That’s it. Nothing about what you yourself tried, why you decided to try that specific thing (what docs did you read that suggested it? What words did you google?), what worked, what didn’t, and what remains. Again and again. It’s just “here’s my problem, you solve it for me”.

Comment: "so ignorance isn’t an excuse." - yes, it is. I have a lot of blind spots. I'm making another post once my timer expires. I google all of my problems before asking here. If I find a link, I read the link. If I find nothing, then there's nothing I can do. Isn't it reasonable to ask questions? Sometimes I can spend time looking for solutions, but my network doesn't contain much information. I've never seen a post like the one you're describing, where someone documents their search. Would it be better to screen record then post a video?

Comment: I don't have the intuition to remember these things. I'm not going to. What do I do now?

Comment: Is there some kind of cure for being stupid? I really want to get better, but I can't. I'm not trolling, and I spend a lot of time trying to make it here. I'm not aware of how bad my writing is. I'm not smooth. Can you provide advice or a place to ask about this?

Comment: That comes across as yet another excuse. It’s always “here’s my situation, nothing **I** can do about it, so now the onus is on you to solve my problem”. No. You write down what you do, as you do it, in detail, what you found, how you tried to apply it, why it didn’t work, what errors it raised, how you tried to address *that* error, and so on. You write it *all in your Q*. No, you don’t record a video, you write it down. Saying “I googled for an hour” is the same as not mentioning you did any research at all. I’m telling you what you have to do; you don’t do it, you don’t get answers.

Comment: You don't need to remember these things. You have a handy dandy question here you can refer back to. Along with the scads of reference material we have on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Is there a place to find the rules and reference material if I don't already know where it is?

Comment: Yes, you can click the question mark icon on the top bar of any site to see its tour and help center pages.

Comment: The vast majority of what we're telling you is provided before you can post your first question on any site. The rest is just spending time getting familiar with it, and learning how it works. Personal investment is important; the more we see you trying, the more readers will respond. That's why showing effort is so important. Nothing wrong with asking for free help. But try to respect it by showing that you've tried yourself; it works out much better for everyone.

Comment: @fbueckert Interstitial pages are only enabled on a small subset of sites.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that there is any Stack Exchange site suitable for broad questions.

It is focused Q&A that these sites are designed for.   To focus a question I think the first step is always to try to ask a single question in your question body.